# Pre-loading data into a SQL Server docker image on start up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am creating a docker-compose.yml file with a few different services in it. One of these services is SQL Server.

My goal is to spin up the container and have the system automatically restore the back up of a database. I'm using the Microsoft "Wide World Importers" sample back up database (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/wide-world-importers-what-is?view=sql-server-ver15) as my `.bak` file.

Here's my yaml:

```
version: "3"
services:

  sql:
    build: ./build/sql
    container_name: sql
    hostname: sql
    networks:
      - network
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - "./data:/data"

networks:
  network:
```

...and my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

ENV SA_PASSWORD [my password]
ENV ACCEPT_EULA Y
ENV MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED true
ENV MSSQL_PID Express

EXPOSE 1433

CMD ["/data/restore.sh"]
```

And finally, my restore.sh.

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P '[my password]' -Q 'RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = "/data/WideWorldImporters-Full.bak"' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 1-2
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P '[my password]' -Q 'RESTORE DATABASE WideWorldImporters FROM DISK = "/data/WideWorldImporters-Full.bak" WITH MOVE "WWI_Primary" TO "/var/opt/mssql/data/WideWorldImporters.mdf", MOVE "WWI_UserData" TO "/var/opt/mssql/data/WideWorldImporters_userdata.ndf", MOVE "WWI_Log" TO "/var/opt/mssql/data/WideWorldImporters.ldf", MOVE "WWI_InMemory_Data_1" TO "/var/opt/mssql/data/WideWorldImporters_InMemory_Data_1"'
```

I can ssh into the container after it's started up and run the restore script, which ends up restoring the database just fine. I know that *parts* of this work.  The container itself on its own works. The restore script works. Putting it all together fails.

What am I doing wrong? Am I approaching this the wrong way? What's the correct way to spin up a SQL Server container with some data in it already?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks, all!

**[EDIT]**. Full output from the docker-compose up command follows:

```
Creating network "retention_network" with the default driver
Building sql
Step 1/7 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
2019-latest: Pulling from mssql/server
59ab41dd721a: Pull complete
57da90bec92c: Pull complete
06fe57530625: Pull complete
5a6315cba1ff: Pull complete
739f58768b3f: Pull complete
3a58fde0fc61: Pull complete
89b44069090d: Pull complete
9d86d733b28b: Pull complete
725e4eb49e7e: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:bbc6d638724b4604ab1201e89e006dcec9efdbced5ff23b680321c1bc6724c2a
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
 ---> d273eadd9675
Step 2/7 : ENV SA_PASSWORD [My password]
 ---> Running in c5db5b3dbd46
Removing intermediate container c5db5b3dbd46
 ---> aaae9a242b75
Step 3/7 : ENV ACCEPT_EULA Y
 ---> Running in e7ca97135ff9
Removing intermediate container e7ca97135ff9
 ---> e2d5b4f405f5
Step 4/7 : ENV MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED true
 ---> Running in f207cad20367
Removing intermediate container f207cad20367
 ---> 99774f595780
Step 5/7 : ENV MSSQL_PID Express
 ---> Running in 4e60c45eda89
Removing intermediate container 4e60c45eda89
 ---> 0137124525dc
Step 6/7 : EXPOSE 1433
 ---> Running in 92ecccf4bc31
Removing intermediate container 92ecccf4bc31
 ---> 79e4778f8b02
Step 7/7 : CMD ["/data/restore.sh"]
 ---> Running in c9278fbd3b6b
Removing intermediate container c9278fbd3b6b
 ---> 287f7f95793a
Successfully built 287f7f95793a
Successfully tagged retention_sql:latest
WARNING: Image for service sql was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating sql ... done
Attaching to sql
sql    | SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default.
sql    | This container is running as user mssql.
sql    | To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.
sql    | Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
sql    | Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.
sql    | Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
sql    | Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
sql    | Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.
sql    | Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
sql exited with code 1
```

Comment: When you put it all together, is the container still up or does it stop?

Comment: It stops.  I'll post the full output.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with running windows in Docker, but: are you running the `restore`, and that completes successfully, and terminates? Because that is the `CMD` that starts in the container, and when that terminates, the container should halt. What is keeping the container alive after `restore.sh` is finished?

Comment: @DavidByers if it stops, it means the container ran everything and there's no foreground thread pending. So if your database starts in the background, that's your issue. Start it in the foreground.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure... for the record, this is not Windows in Docker.  It's running on Ubuntu.  This is also my first "get my feet wet" project with docker-compose, so I'm not 100% certain that I'm approaching this the right way.  Ultimately the goal is to spin up a SQL Server in Docker and pre-load it with data.  A lot of the solutions I've seen out there employ docker run commands and aren't wrapped up in a docker-compose file nicely, but this HAS to be something that is possible, and "should" be simple, right?

Comment: "should" is an evil word.

Comment: @DavidByers If it's Ubuntu then I am pretty sure what is described in the answer I posted is the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that, the way it is currently written, the `restore.sh` script is completing successfully, and then the container terminates (which is what is supposed to happen). Docker containers only live as long as that command continues to run. I would rearrange it like this:

```
RUN /data/restore.sh
[CMD "<DB command>"]
```

The data will get populated in a separate image layer that will be included in the final image that will be used to run the container. But the command that runs, `<db command>`, needs to start the DBMS and then *not* return, because once that command returns the container is going to stop.

I tried running with a copy/paste of your `docker-compose.yml` file, and this Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
CMD ["/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr", "--accept-eula"]
```

That worked for me.

As an alternative, you could keep `restore.sh` as `CMD`, but then add `/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula` at the end of that script. That will start the database after the restore completes and prevent the container from exiting.